# Hiding an object from output in Rego Policy

Tags: policy, open-policy-agent, rego

I created a Rego Policy but I would like to hide some of the objects from the output of the Rego.

Lets take this simple Rego as an example.

```
package cats

default cats := false

cats{
input.cat == my_cats[_]}

my_cats:= {
"Pumpkin Spice",
"Dr Meow"
}
```

Input:

```
{
    "cat": "Pumpkin Spice"
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "cats": true,
    "my_cats": [
        "Dr Meow",
        "Pumpkin Spice"
    ]
}
```

I would like to hide the `my_cats` Object from the Output, while only keeping the `cat`.

There is the `mask` functionality, but I couldn't get it to work since I think it's only supposed to working with the content of the `input`.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The response you get depends on what you query for. So if you query the `cats` rule, you'd get only `true` back. You can test this with e.g. `opa eval -d policy.rego 'data.cats.cats'`

The first element following `data` would be the package (`cats`), and the next element the rule in that package (also named `cats`).

If you're using the Rego Playground for evaluation, you can simply select the rule and the "Evaluate" button will change to "Evaluate Selection", which will evaluate only the rule if selected.